# Upgrade/Migrate HDInsight Cluster to Last Version

Tags: azure, hadoop, azure-hdinsight

I'm sure this is posted somewhere or has been communicated but I just can't seem to find anything about upgrading/migrating from a HDInsight cluster from one version to the next.

A little background.  We've been using Hive with HDInsight to store all of our IIS logs since 1/24/2014.  We love it and it provides good insight to our teams.

I recently was reviewing http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-component-versioning/ and noticed that our version of HDInsight (2.1.3.0.432823) is no longer supported and will be deprecated in May.  That got me to thinking about how to get onto version 3.2.  I just can't seem to find anything about how to go about doing this.

Does anyone have any insight into if this is possible and if so how?

Answer (score 3):

HDInsight uses Azure Storage for persistent data, so you should be able to create a new cluster and point to the old data, as long as you are using `wasb://*/*` for your storage locations.  This article has a great overview of the storage architecture: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/hdinsight-use-blob-storage/

If you are using Hive and have not set up a customized metastore, then you may need to save or recreate some of the tables.  Here's a blog post that covers some of those scenarios: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2014/05/01/hdinsight-backup-and-restore-hive-table.aspx

You can configure a new cluster and add the existing cluster's storage container as an "additional" storage account to test this out without first taking down the current cluster.  [Just be sure not to have both clusters using the same container as their default storage](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bigdatasupport/archive/2015/02/12/problems-when-using-a-shared-default-storage-container-with-multiple-hdinsight-clusters.aspx).

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I was thinking this was what I would have to do. I'm going to try it today at work and i'll let you know.